# Chrome align-items: baseline for select and input elements

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, flexbox

I have built a form using flex box and it works beautifully in Firefox, Edge and IE11.

Unfortunately in Chrome the text in the spans isn't aligning consistently. It is fine if followed by a select but when followed by an input the text appears to align to the bottom rather than the baeline.

I am using baseline instead of center to account for potentially different font sizes.

**Incorrect layout in Chrome**

[image: Incorrect layou in Chrome]

**Correct layout in FF**

[image: Correct layout in FF]

I have simplified my code and posted to 
http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/jrmbJP

```css
form,
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: .3rem 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
fieldset span {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
}
input,
select,
textarea {
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label>
      <span>Label</span>
      <input type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Label</span>
      <select>
        <option value="" selected="" disabled=""></option>
        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
        <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
        <option value="Ms">Mx</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to add `placeholder=" "` to your inputs and they will align perfectly.

Comment: Can you explain why ?

Comment: I tried it, and it works!

I can only imagine that perhaps Chrome isn't setting the baseline of text inputs until they contain text.  It would be nice to not have to put this on every input though. I am building a site with many many forms.

 placeholder="" without the space, doesn't work.

Comment: This can be set in jQuery with $('input').attr('placeholder', ' '); so you don't have to put the placeholder in everywhere.

Comment: Mind blown! Just want to add adding the placeholder through dev tools won't change anything. The placeholder needs to be there when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `align-items: baseline;`. Instead use `align-items: center;`

Here is the updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRyGvo)

```css
form,
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: .3rem 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
fieldset span {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
}
input,
select,
textarea {
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label>
      <span>Label</span>
      <input type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Label</span>
      <select>
        <option value="" selected="" disabled=""></option>
        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
        <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
        <option value="Ms">Mx</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I had ruled out using center as I want to be absolutely sure of the text baseline being aligned. If you use center, if any text varies in size, the baselines end up being misaligned.