# jQuery select multiple types of text based inputs

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jQuery hack to fix a bug in Chrome that causes alignment problems in empty fields. [Chrome align-items: baseline for select and input elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700227/chrome-align-items-baseline-for-select-and-input-elements)

```
$('input:text').each(function(i,el) {
    if (!el.value || el.value == '') {
      el.placeholder = ' ';
    }
});
```

I want to affect all text style inputs (text,email,date,tel,number etc) without affecting radios checkboxes and range sliders as it seems a neater way to do it.

Is there a way to do this without listing each input type individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `type=checkbox` and `type=radio`

```
$('input:not([type='radio']:not([type='checkbox']))')
```

Comment: Thanks @void, just had to remove the quotes to get it to work.
$('input:not([type=radio]:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=range]))')
  .each(function(i,el) {
    if (!el.value || el.value == '') {
      el.placeholder = ' ';
    }
});